# Groupby key and select max date for key from given list

Tags: java, java-stream

```
   Map<groupname,Optional<Person>> test= Personlist.streams.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.getgroup(), 
        Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(x -> x.getCreateDate()))));
```

I was able to iterate and find the max record after using above condition after this i need to iterate and set values for each group based on the max date which was fetched above

Sample record

```
group 1, 1/1/2020
group 1, 1/2/2020
group 1, 1/3/2020
group 2, 1/1/2020
group 2, 2/1/2020
group 2, 3/1/2020
```

Excepted output: ( i have  groups which is constant)
 1. if Group 1 exist set group 1 max Create date = 1/3/2020 else null
 2.   if    Group 2 exist set group 2 max create date = 3/1/2020 else null
 3.   if    Group 3 exist set group 3 max create date =  null ( since
    doesn't    exist)'

`if ( group 1 exist) 
{

setgroup1createdate(maxcreatedate) } else setgroup1createdate(null)
}`

... how many group present

Comment: Can you add expected output as well ?

Comment: added  expected output

Comment: Fixed group is in list ? Can you add how is fixed group stored. ?

Comment: yes group is part of the list 
Amit, group1, 1/1/2020
Amit, group1, 1/2/2020

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the max date in each of the groups based on the search for the max date in the `personlist`, you could do it by first using the `reducing` method to create a `Map<String, Optional<Date>>` instance, where you store the max date for every group:

```
Map<String, Optional<Date>> collect =
   personList.stream().collect(groupingBy(x -> x.getGroup(),
      mapping(Person::getCreationDate, maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Date::getTime)))));
System.out.println(collect);
```

Then you iterate your groups and set the max date from the map:

```
groupList.stream().forEach(g -> 
   g.setCreationDate(collect.getOrDefault(g.getGroup(), Optional.empty()).orElse(null)));
System.out.println(personList);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Collectors.collectingAndThen` function.

```
 Map<String, Date> data =  Personlist
  .stream()
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    x -> x.getGroup(), 
    Collectors.collectingAndThen(
       Collectors.maxBy(
          Comparator.comparing(x -> x.getCreatedDate)), 
          (x) -> x.map(x -> x.getCreatedDate).orElse(null)
       )
    )
 );
```

It will have a mapping for `group` and respective date.

Now, setting null for non-existent group won't be required as default value will be `null` in `Map` if key (`group`) is not present.

Comment: thank you lucid Collectors.collectingAndThen worked that was the piece i was missing earlier